# Android SDK offline installation

Tags: android

I have installed android SDK offline. But on my AVD Manager, on its left pane there is only
 ->Virtual Dvices->Installed Packages and ->Available Packages only. 
 There is no settings shown on the left pane. Is it a problem ? Also when I am running google  api 10(2.3.3),the emulator is getting stuck. Can you please say an offline installation method for completely installing Google api 10. I am not able to install it online .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check out this site**[Contains Android Packages you can download](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=725545)

Comment: These packages are too old ... !!