# Where To Download Android SDK for Offline Installation

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm using Ubuntu and I already have installed only JDK and android studio 3.01.
It's restricted for me to download from android SDK manager by Google. I have already studied similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296349/android-sdk-offline-installation). so this is not a duplicate neither off-topic question i think, and those questions both are for older versions and unclear for me.

**TL DR,**
Is there any way to download latest android SDK from download link (not using apt-get) and move it offline to an computer running linux(ubuntu) that already have android studio 3.0.1 and jdk installed.

Comment: please let me know if you resolved this am in same sutiation @yekanchi

Comment: i didn't found any way except i found some way that google can't prevent direct download through android sdk manager.

Comment: so is they any url...so i can download full sdk manager?my company network restricting me to download directly so i need url to send request for sdk manager url access.

Comment: just download android studio, sdk manager is part of the android studio, then download sdk using sdk-manager , sdk is just a folder containing the build tools and needed libraries, then you can move it to offline environment.
link for the latest android studio is
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/3.4.0.18/android-studio-ide-183.5452501-windows.exe

Comment: ya i know this.but thing is my company not allowing sdkpackage.after installation only sdk manager package is missing.so for that i have to send url access request to enable sdk manager.but am not getting that URL.Do you have any idea how to get only SDK manager package url?